# How to resize form in panel ( C# )

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, panel

I create new form and add into panel in main form. When I click maximum in main form. Panel can dock fill in main form but form in panel can not resize.

add form into panel

```
    frm2 = new frm2();
    frm2.TopLevel = false;
    frm2.AutoScroll = true;

    // test
    frm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    splitmain.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm2);
    frm2.Show();
```

Panel.SizeChanged

```
        splitmain.Panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        splitmain.Panel2.Controls.Remove( frm2 );
        frm2.Size = new Size(inPanel.Width, inPanel.Height);
        frm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        splitmain.Panel2.Controls.Add( frm2 );
        splitmain.Panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Picture

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to set the size when you use DockStyle.Fill? It renders your size setting useless.

Comment: I want to increase size and use DockStyle.Fill but It not work.

Comment: If you use DockStyle.Fill, frm2 will automatically use the available space in its parent container (Panel2). You don't need to set frm2.Size.

Comment: After //test Comment Line. I has set DockStyle.Fill in frm2. But It not work. I test to resize and set frm2.Dock again. Result : It not work.

Comment: you'd better post some screenshot and maybe image from paint what you have and what your target design is..

Comment: try to use the anchor property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use Anchors on the Panel Too, Set them to  RIGHT | LEFT | TOP | BOTTOM for a all direction resizing with the container..

if the pannel is nested in another panel, notice that the container should have the same Anchors too...

```
splitmain.Panel2.Anchor = Anchor.Left | Anchor.Right | Anchor.Top | Anchor.Bottom;
```

play with Anchors till you get the hang of it!

you can watch this movie to get little bit more familiar:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO_zbWVklS8

Comment: Thank for answer But It not work.It can not auto fill when main form maximum windows.

Comment: My feel is that your Main Form Resizes, but Panel2 does not.
because Panel2 is not Anchored nor Docked.